Permission denied When uploading file Docker Fastapi
I'm facing an error  when am try to upload a file to FastAPI endpoint it work fine on localhost but I get an error when run it on a container.
The error I get:
File "/app/main.py", line 26, in say_hello
    with open(file_path, "wb") as f:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'uploads/h.png'

My upload endpoint:
@app.post("/letter")
async def say_hello(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    
    file_path = f"uploads/{file.filename}"

    with open(file_path, "wb") as f:
        f.write(await file.read())
    return process_image(file_path)

My Dockerfile:
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.12.3
FROM python:${PYTHON_VERSION}-slim as base

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

WORKDIR /app

ARG UID=10001
RUN adduser \
    --disabled-password \
    --gecos "" \
    --home "/nonexistent" \
    --shell "/sbin/nologin" \
    --no-create-home \
    --uid "${UID}" \
    appuser

# Set the permissions for all files
RUN chown -R appuser:appgroup /app

RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/pip \
    --mount=type=bind,source=requirements.txt,target=requirements.txt \
    python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

# Switch to the non-privileged user to run the application.
USER appuser

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]

I've tried setting permission for the default user by adding permission on Dockerfile but nothing changed :
# Set the permissions for all files
RUN chown -R appuser:appgroup /app


Your chown command won't work because there is no appgroup group on the image. The group would have the same name as the user, appuser.

Permissions on Copied Folder
I believe that you need to change the file ownership after you have copied them across onto your image.
ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.12.3
FROM python:${PYTHON_VERSION}-slim as base

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

WORKDIR /app

ARG UID=10001
RUN adduser \
    --disabled-password \
    --gecos "" \
    --home "/nonexistent" \
    --shell "/sbin/nologin" \
    --no-create-home \
    --uid "${UID}" \
    appuser

RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/pip \
    --mount=type=bind,source=requirements.txt,target=requirements.txt \
    python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

RUN chown -R appuser:appuser /app/uploads

EXPOSE 8000

USER appuser

CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]

That will result in the /app/uploads directory on any container being writable by appuser. It assumes that there is a uploads directory on the host that will be copied across onto the image.
There is a problem with this though: any files uploaded onto a running container will only exist within the container and will be lost when the container stops.
Volume Mount
If you want to retain those files then you probably want to do a volume mount when running the image. You'd do something like -v ./uploads/:/app/uploads when you execute docker run. However, in this case you need to ensure that the uploads/ directory on the host will be writable on the container too. One way to do this would be to give the user, group and other write access to the folder on the host.
chmod a+w uploads/

There are probably better ways to do this, but this is certainly an option that works.
